# update ACF repeater with file upload saving only the last file uploaded

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Wordpress with ACF plugin and I want to add new rows to repeater field, One of the sub field is file.

it saves all the values I'm inserting correctly but for some reason removes the other files saved before.

my code look like this:

```
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
$params['field_58fcbc968b60c'] = $_POST['user_name'];

if(isset($_POST['expert_question']) && !empty($_POST['expert_question']))
{
    $params['field_58fcbcc08b60d'] = addslashes($_POST['expert_question']);
}

if(isset($_POST['user_email_addr']) && !empty($_POST['user_email_addr']) && filter_var($_POST['user_email_addr'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    $user_email = $_POST['user_email_addr'];
}



if(count($_FILES) && isset($_FILES['expert_question_file']) && !empty($_FILES['expert_question_file']['name']))
{
    $allow_extension = ['pdf','png','jpg','gif','doc','docx','xls','csv'];
    $file_info = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['expert_question_file'], ['test_form' => false]);
    $temp = explode(".",$file_info['file']);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if(in_array(strtolower($extension),$allow_extension))
    {

        $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $attachment = [
            'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'].'/'.basename($file_info['file']),
            'post_mime_type' => $file_info['type'],
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
        ];

        $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment);
        $params['field_58fcbcfd8b60e'] = $attachment_id;
    }else{
        $res = "Invalid file extension";
    }

}

if(have_rows('field_58fcbc758b60b',$post_id)){
    $expert_questions_repeater = get_field('field_58fcbc758b60b', $post_id);
    $expert_questions_repeater[] = $params;
}else{
    $expert_questions_repeater = [];
    $expert_questions_repeater[] = $params;
}

update_field('field_58fcbc758b60b', $expert_questions_repeater, $post_id);
```

Any idea what can cause this? thank's all, peace & love :)

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was - I had to the attachment id to the field

```
$params['field_58fcbcfd8b60e'] = $attachment_id;
```

but the field defined to return "image url" instead of image id.